# how to find critical values of Wilcoxon signed rank test in R

Tags: r

I just can't find it anywhere. I know there's a `qwilcox()` function, but for some reason it only shows critical values of Mann-Whitney for me. Here's the [table of Critical Values of Wilcoxon](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2VTEwur53PDUW00NFF6VG9acGM/edit). For example if I have n=8 and α=0.05 two tailed, how to find in in R? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the help for the `qwilcox` function (`?qwilcox`), under "See also" it says:

> See Also:

```
 ‘wilcox.test’ to calculate the statistic from data, find p values
 and so on.

 Distributions for standard distributions, including ‘dsignrank’
 for the distribution of the _one-sample_ Wilcoxon signed rank
 statistic.
```

So try `?dsignrank`... and you'll also see `qsignrank`